# Why is my rep being reduced without being detailed on my rep page?

Tags: support, reputation

Why is my rep being reduced? I had 47 yesterday then got +25 and today I am 26. Why can’t I answer questions, post questions, or comment without being targeted?

This is a bug, the math doesn't work here. Come on why can’t I get some help here?

Comment: Really? You are right, but regarding your reputation that reduced: I reckon +25 is for my question as I choose and voted it up, but I assume there could some users (who upvoted you), then they returned their upvotes of you, then you reduced ... (as a probability) (AFAIK)

Answer (score 3):

It was -50 for what was deemed an offensive post then that post was deleted by the "community" bot. It shows up on the rep page when you check the box to show deleted posts.